# Why such output?

Tags: c

I was doing an example of the C language and tried example shown below. I thought it should print the string **`Study Tonight strings`**, but it is giving the output **`Study Tonight stringsStudyTonight`** Why it is so ? I thought that even the `char str[7]` array size is right.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main() {
    char ch[20]="Study Tonight ";
    printf("%s",ch);
    char str[7]="strings";
    printf("%s",str);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: I’ll let someone elaborate in an answer, but in short, you’re not leaving enough space for a null terminator, so it is omitted and it keeps on reading past the end of the string.

Comment: Its an example of buffer overflow..

Comment: If you're not going to do anything with a char array other than initialize it, leave the brackets blank and let the compiler allocate the right amount of space: `char str[]="strings";`

Comment: Unfortunately, gcc does not count the terminating zero as part of the string... Only with the more obvious erroneous `char str[6]="strings";`, I get a `warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long`.

Comment: Also unfortunately: with a peek in to the generated assembler code, I cannot find out why the first string is repeated again. Because Of Stack? (It may be Undefined Behavior but it certainly seems repeatable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
char str[7]="strings";
```

Is already undefined behavior, as the initializer is 7 characters of text plus 1 null terminator, so you need 8 bytes of storage, not 7.  Please turn on your compiler warnings and it will catch such trivial problems for you.  If you use GCC or Clang, it's like this:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed to count the null character. The size of the array should be no of characters + 1 for null terminator. So in this case it should be char `char str[8] = "strings"`.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the string `NULL` terminator is necessary. If you wont allocate a space for `NULL`, leads to Undefined behavior.

```
 char str[7]="strings"; // Undefined Behavior
```

In this assignment, you have allocated space for only the string(7 characters). But at the end of the string `NULL` is necessary.

So Try any of the following changes-

```
 char str[8]="strings";
```

or

```
 char str[]="strings";
```